# Add Time Together From Previous Row in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am using Microsoft Access 2016 and I have a table where the goal is using the provided start time for each date, add the given Slot to the Start to calculate the End time. Where I am having difficulties is where Start is null, it is to pull the previous records' End time as its Start time and repeat the process.

Below is a sample table of data:

| Day | PrimaryKey | AbovePrimaryKey | Start | Slot | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/19/2022 | 171 |  | 4:00:00 PM | 2:30 |  |
| 9/19/2022 | 172 | 171 |  | 2:30 |  |
| 9/19/2022 | 173 | 172 |  | 1:30 |  |
| 9/20/2022 | 174 | 173 | 11:00:00 AM | 1:30 |  |
| 9/20/2022 | 175 | 174 |  | 1:30 |  |
| 9/20/2022 | 176 | 175 |  | 2:30 |  |
| 9/20/2022 | 177 | 176 |  | 2:30 |  |
| 9/20/2022 | 178 | 177 |  | 1:00 |  |
| 9/20/2022 | 179 | 178 |  | 1:00 |  |

Below is what I am wanting as the result:

| Day | PrimaryKey | Start | Slot | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/19/2022 | 171 | 4:00:00 PM | 2:30 | 6:30:00 PM |
| 9/19/2022 | 172 | 6:30:00 PM | 2:30 | 8:30:00 PM |
| 9/19/2022 | 173 | 8:30:00 PM | 1:30 | 10:00:00 PM |
| 9/20/2022 | 174 | 11:00:00 AM | 1:30 | 12:30:00 PM |
| 9/20/2022 | 175 | 12:30:00 PM | 1:30 | 2:00:00 PM |
| 9/20/2022 | 176 | 2:00:00 PM | 2:30 | 4:30:00 PM |
| 9/20/2022 | 177 | 4:30:00 PM | 2:30 | 7:00:00 PM |
| 9/20/2022 | 178 | 7:00:00 PM | 1:00 | 8:00:00 PM |
| 9/20/2022 | 179 | 8:00:00 PM | 1:00 | 9:00:00 PM |

I was able to get the previous row's primary key to use in reference in some subquery to pull the previous row's End, but am unable to determine how to do so, especially since I have also have to calculate Start and End.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lag function in Microsoft Access (Window Function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227887/lag-function-in-microsoft-access-window-function)

Comment: My issues is needing to both replicate the lag function and use subqueries / correlated queries to do the calculation. When I tried that option it actually returned the same PrimaryKey as the row vs the one above.

Comment: can you show us what you tried, it will involve, you need of course some more logic to it, but the basics should fit just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with four sets of subqueries:

```sql
SELECT 
    SampleData.Day, 
    SampleData.PrimaryKey, 

        (Select S2.Start 
        From SampleData As S2 
        Where S2.PrimaryKey = 
            (Select Max(S.PrimaryKey) 
            From SampleData As S 
            Where S.Start Is Not Null And S.PrimaryKey <= SampleData.PrimaryKey)) +

        (Select CDate(IIf(Sum(S3.Slot) Is Null, #00:00#, Sum(S3.Slot))) 
        From SampleData As S3 
        Where S3.PrimaryKey < SampleData.PrimaryKey And S3.PrimaryKey >= 
            (Select Max(S.PrimaryKey) 
            From SampleData As S 
            Where S.Start Is Not Null and S.PrimaryKey <= SampleData.PrimaryKey)) As [Start],

    SampleData.Slot, 

        (Select S2.Start 
        From SampleData As S2 
        Where S2.PrimaryKey = 
            (Select Max(S.PrimaryKey) 
            From SampleData As S 
            Where S.Start Is Not Null And S.PrimaryKey <= SampleData.PrimaryKey)) +

        (Select CDate(Sum(S3.Slot)) 
        From SampleData As S3 
        Where S3.PrimaryKey <= SampleData.PrimaryKey And S3.PrimaryKey >= 
            (Select Max(S.PrimaryKey) 
            From SampleData As S 
            Where S.Start Is Not Null And S.PrimaryKey <= SampleData.PrimaryKey)) As [End] 

FROM 
    SampleData;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I get #Error for both my Start and End values for all my rows when I run that query.

Comment: @hansup The issue was the Start was formatted as Short Text by mistake. That resolved the #Error. It did look like I was having a different issue where it wasn't pull the record above's information, but I cleared that up (no change in the query though).

Thank you for the assistance, these correlated queries  & subqueries are a bit over me. Need to learn more about them.